# Regex: search all data in text

Tags: regex

I try to extract info from text, but some of my samples can't pass the test.

Test data:

```
Д. Большая Пустынь
ДНП "Залесье"
ДНП "Косулинские дачи"
ДНП "Лесные дачи"
ДНП "Мешков Лог"
ДНП "Подкова"
х. Каширинский
село Куяново
с.Черемисское
```

And using expression

```
re.search(r"""^(?:[Дд]еревня|[Сс]ело|[ДдСсПпXx]|[Дд]ер|[Пп]ос[eё]лок|ДНП)\.?\s?"?[\w\s\.]+"?
                  |[\w\s]+[Сс]ельсовет""", test_str)
```

Comment: How do you plan to match `с. У Чёрта На Куличках`? I understand you want to extract these values from a larger text, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  ahah, maybe `r'c\.?\s?[a-zA-Z\s]+'` . You are right, from text

Comment: Well, you may only rely on the fact that all words after the main word are capitalized. A PCRE regex (in Python, use PyPi regex module): [`r"\b(?:[Дд](?:еревня)?|[Сс](?:ело)?|[Дд](?:ер)?|[Пп](?:ос[eё]лок)?|[Хх](?:утор)?|ДНП)\b\.?\s*(?:"([^"]+)"|(\p{Lu}\S*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\S*)*)\b)|(\p{Lu}\S*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\S*)*)\s+[Сс]ельсовет''`](https://regex101.com/r/XTktkJ/2).

Comment: See http://rextester.com/KLU18792.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need extract all text, that I write in question, not only name

Comment: Easy - http://rextester.com/DSNF69568

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you!